# Understand relationship between multiple dummy variables in R

Tags: r, regression, frequency-analysis

I have the following data frame:

```
id       dummy1      dummy2       dummy3      dummy4
2          1           1            1           0  
3          0           0            0           1  
4          1           1            1           0  
5          0           0            1           0
```

I am trying to come up with a way to see if certain dummy variables appear together more often than others. In this example, if dummy1 is 1, all other dummies are more likely to be 1, too. I tried calculating frequencies, but it becomes very inconvenient for more than two variables.

To give you more context, the dummies stand for different products purchased at a supermarket. I am trying to see if a person who purchases one product (tomatoes, for instance) is more likely to buy a different type (lettuce etc) with it.

Thank you!

Comment: "I am not looking for a specific code at the moment, just ideas for packages/regression models etc." - that is off-topic on stackoverflow, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the correlation between variable in your case. It is the easiest approach, it gives you a number between -1 and 1, 1 meaning the two variable are identical (-1 they behave oppositely), and 0 that they are uncorrelated, so they behave independently.

There is a function for that and it is `cor`. You can use it directly on your data.frame:

```
plouf <- read.table(text = "id       dummy1      dummy2       dummy3      dummy4
2          1           1            1           0
3          0           0            0           1
4          1           1            1           0
5          0           0            1           0",header = T)


cor(plouf[,-1]) 

           dummy1     dummy2     dummy3     dummy4
dummy1  1.0000000  1.0000000  0.5773503 -0.5773503
dummy2  1.0000000  1.0000000  0.5773503 -0.5773503
dummy3  0.5773503  0.5773503  1.0000000 -1.0000000
dummy4 -0.5773503 -0.5773503 -1.0000000  1.0000000
```

Here dummy1 and dummy2 are identical (correlation equal to 1), and that dummy4/dummy1 tends to behave oppositely dummy1/dummy3 and dummy2/dummy3 tneds to behave similarly.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! In my example, I have around 50 dummies, which will generate a 50 by 50 matrix based on ~1k observations. Do you think cor will work with that much data just fine? Also, is there a way to see deeper connections between the dummies: for instance, if dummy1 and dummy2 are both 1, dummy3 is more likely to be 1.

Comment: cor will work just fine on your data. For the deeper connection you can create a variable that is  `dumm1 == 1 & dummy2 == 1` and do the correlation